# Assigning value to array at certain index

Tags: bash, shell-script

Hi am trying to write a script that updates a row read from file ,
Every thing is working fine so far except the following mentioned 
line at the end

here is my script :

```
#!/bin/bash     

#INITIALIZE PATHS
DB_PATH=${1}      
DATA_PATH="$DB_PATH/data/"
METADATA_PATH="$DB_PATH/metadata"   

#LOAD THE META DB FILE AND READ DATABASE NAME IN DB_NAME 
#READ ALSO COLUMNS IN AN ARRAY CALLED TABLE_NAMES                      
METADATA_LOAD=$(<"$METADATA_PATH/DB")
IFS=$'+'
read -a NAMES <<< "$METADATA_LOAD"



#PROMPET FOR TABLE TO UPDATE
echo ""
echo ""
echo ""
echo "You Currently Working with Database ${NAMES[0]}" 
echo ""
echo "You Have The Following Tables to Choose From :"
IFS=' '
for token in ${NAMES[@]:1}
do
echo "  $token"
done
echo ""
echo ""
echo ""
echo "Please Write The Name Of The Table You Want To Update :"
read CURRENT_TABLE


#Form META DATA TABLE FILE PATH
TABLE_DATA_PATH="$DB_PATH/data/$CURRENT_TABLE"
TABLE_METADATA_PATH="$DB_PATH/metadata/$CURRENT_TABLE"


#PROMPET WHICH COLUMN IS NEEDED TO CHECK FOR EQUALITY
echo ""
echo ""
echo ""
echo "The Table You Selected Have The Following Columns"
i=0 
TABLE_METADATA=$(<"$TABLE_METADATA_PATH")
IFS='+'
read -a CURRENT_TABLE_META <<< "$TABLE_METADATA"
IFS=' '
for token in ${CURRENT_TABLE_META[@]:1}
do
i=$(($i+1))
echo $i $token
done
echo "Please Enter The Number Column to Check For Equality"
read TEST_COLUMN_NUM
echo ""
echo ""
echo "Please Enter The Column Value to Check For Equality"
read TEST_COLUMN_VAL

echo "Please Enter The Column Number to Modify"
read MODIFY_COLUMN_NUM

echo "Please Enter The New Column Value"
read MODIFY_COLUMN_VAL

#Form DATA TABLE FILE PATH
TABLE_DATA=$(<"$TABLE_DATA_PATH") 


IFS=' '
read -a ROWS_ARRAY <<< "$TABLE_DATA"  




for CURRENT_ROW_INDEX in ${!ROWS_ARRAY[@]}
do

  IFS=':'
  read -a COLUMNS_ARRAY <<< "${ROWS_ARRAY[CURRENT_ROW_INDEX]}"

   for CURRENT_COL_INDEX in ${!COLUMNS_ARRAY[@]} 
   do

       if [[ ${COLUMNS_ARRAY[$CURRENT_COL_INDEX]} == $TEST_COLUMN_VAL  &&  $CURRENT_COL_INDEX -eq $(($TEST_COLUMN_NUM-1)) ]]
       then

           IFS=' '
           COLUMNS_ARRAY[$MODIFY_COLUMN_NUM] = "ABC"



       fi   

   done
done
```

I did not finish the script yet but I have an error at the line :

```
 COLUMNS_ARRAY[$MODIFY_COLUMN_NUM] = "ABC"
```

it gives me Error

> ./Update: line 91: COLUMNS_ARRAY[3]: command not found

I want to assign to the array at the given index replacing the old value,
please help me to know the reason of error and how to solve it

Comment: I would advise in the future not saying "a code", it does not sounds well. A shell script usually is best saved in a file with an ".sh" extension.

Comment: you mean the word "code" I mentioned above ? .. if you mean so .. that's un accurate use of term may be because i am a beginner ..thanks for your advice :D

Comment: @ikkachu thanks that was the reason ... you are correct ..it worked perfectly fine thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same thing as with regular variable assignment in the shell, don't put whitespace around the `=`.

Given `i=123`, this is an assignment to index `123` in `array`:

```
array[$i]="abc"
```

This tries to run a command called `array[123]` (or whatever the result if a filename matching that as a glob pattern is found):

```
array[$i] = "abc"
```

---

Also, every time you use `${array[@]}`, with or without `!` or `:n:m`, you are likely to want to put quotes around it. Without quotes, the array values are subject to word splitting, with them, they aren't.

You have, e.g. `for token in ${NAMES[@]:1}` and `for .. in ${!ROWS_ARRAY[@]}`